# MySql - Select From ID To ID

Tags: php, mysql

How i can select on php with mysql command from ID lets say 13000 to ID 50000, or lets say from ID 60000 to id 200000 ...

I try to find how but didnt find nothing helpful

---

Comment: `WHERE ID >=13000 AND ID<=50000`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM your_tbl 
WHERE column1 BETWEEN 60000 AND 200000;
```

Comment: You beat me to it ;-)